I've been making rhythm games like 'Cytus' with unity but I have a problem with overlapped notes
If I press a key where the decision line overlaps two notes, both notes disappear at once. I've been thinking about it for hours, but it didn't work, so I'm asking a question...
When creating each note, a noteID was assigned and the numbers increased sequentially starting from 1.
I created a note number to react to next in the game manager, and if the two are the same, I made that note disappear. As the notePassCount value in the game manager rises, all overlapping notes disappear.
GameManager.cs
    public void NoteHit() //GameManager.cs
    {
        Debug.Log("Hit!");
        notePassCount++;
    }

    public void NoteMissed()
    {
        Debug.Log("Missed!");
        notePassCount++;
    }

NoteScript.cs
void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
        {
            if (canBePressed == true && noteNumbering.noteID == GameManager.instance.notePassCount)
            {
                ParentObject.SetActive(false);
                GameManager.instance.NoteHit();

            }
        }
    }

    public void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.tag == "SecondNeedle")
        {

            canBePressed = true;
        }
    }
    public void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.tag == "SecondNeedle" && ParentObject.activeSelf)
        {

            canBePressed = false;
            GameManager.instance.NoteMissed();
            ParentObject.SetActive(false);
            

        }
    }

NoteNumbering
public class NoteNumbering : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int noteID;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }

    public void SetNoteID(int id)
    {
        noteID = id;
    }
}

Every Note has notescript.cs and noteNumbering.cs

not everyone has played cytus and this gives no explanation as to what you mean by "decision overlaps two notes"

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
